# How can I replace not supported TRY_CONVERT function on an old SQL Server 2008 version?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not so into database and I am finding the following difficulties. I am working on a pretty old version of **SQL Server**:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4042.0 (X64)   Mar 26 2015 21:18:04   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

The problem is that I have this query:

```
SELECT [Sottocategoria]
      ,[IdSottocategoria]
      ,[IdCategoria]
      ,[Note]
FROM [dbo].[PROT_TITOLARIO]
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(hierarchyid,'/'+REPLACE(IdSottocategoria,'.','/')+'/')
```

that is going into error:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

I think that I can't increase the **compatibility level** of the DB because it is too old, infact doing:

```
ALTER DATABASE GHELLA_CRI SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

I obtain this error message:

```
Msg 15048, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100.
```

So the problem seems to be this **TRY_CONVERT** function that seems not be supported by **SQL Server 2008**.

There is a way to replace it with something similar supported by this SQL Server version?

Here a query sample: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0650397514372818b10958901c98add

Comment: Please show us sample data.  For the most part, there is nothing which `TRY_CONVERT` can do which regular `CONVERT` cannot also do.

Comment: Can you post some example values that cannot be converted? One solution is to detect strings that cannot be converted to hierarchyid and skip them.

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` was added in SQL Server 2012 yes. The documentation won't tell you this, as SQL Server 2008 is now completely out of support; so `TRY_CONVERT` is available in all *supported* versions of SQL Server.

Comment: What is the definition of your custom data type `hierarchyId`?

Comment: Also, why are you using SP2 and not the GDR version? SP3 came out years  ago, and what you have isn't patched against Spectre or Melt down either.

Comment: @SalmanA posted a sample at the end of my original post

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Trying to replace TRY_CONVERT with CONVERT it give me the following error: "Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "hierarchyid": 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 24001: SqlHierarchyId.Parse failed because the input string '/IWG/' is not a valid string representation of a SqlHierarchyId node."

Comment: @Larnu is not my compamy DB. It is the DB used by a client

Comment: I still don't see any sample data in your question.

Comment: Honestly, the lack of patching on the server (along with the fact that it's using unsupported technology) is a huge concern.

Comment: @andrea I looked at the data and looks like the data is not hierrchyId but you're using this as a "trick" to sort values such as 1, 1.1 and 1.1.1. Is that correct?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is the sample: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0650397514372818b10958901c98add

Comment: @SalmanA yes, you are right

Comment: FYI, this is a follow on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391194/how-can-i-correctly-order-by-this-varchar-field-representing-a-multiple-level-or).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filling somes blanks here with my own guesses, but basing on what the OP has, I suspect we could do something like this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[PROT_TITOLARIO] PT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN PT.IdSottocategoria LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' THEN NULL ELSE PT.IdSottocategoria END)) TC(IdSottocategoria)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(hierarchyid,'/'+REPLACE(TC.IdSottocategoria,'.','/')+'/')))V(Hid)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN V.Hid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         V.Hid,
         PT.IdSottocategoria;
```

I use a `CASE` expression to check that the value of `IdSottocategoria` only contains numerical values and `.`'s and then just `CONVERT` those values. That works for the sample values the OP supplied: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b60b446d9b05299201160ce3b1fc790a)

To reiterate my comments, SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 is a really old version of SQL Server. SP3 came out some time ago for 2008R2, and SP2 is **not** patched against the Spectre and Meltdown vulnerabilities. Even if you aren't updating the version of SQL Server for a bit (which should heavily be reconsidered) I cannot more strongly suggest you get that server updated to [SP3 GDR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057113). This is especially true if you are in a country that has GDPR (or similar) legislation, as your local authority will see unpatched (and unsupported) software as a huge concern and will not reflect well on the list of preventative measures in the result of a breach.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8010d2239960f97503dc7116df6827a

Comment: If I'd known the OP was using an unsopported version of SQL Server before, I'd have never used `TRY_CONVERT` in my initial answer. How *foolish* of me to assume that they were using supported technology. >_<

Comment: #@Larnu it seems to works fine. Great job !!! But I have some doubts:
1) What do you mean with "OP"?
2) You are selecting on the PROT_TITOLARIO table (aliased as PT) but what is the meaning of CROSS APPLY? I read that is something like a JOIN but I can't see the exact meaning....sorry but I am not into DB and I need to understand how it is working

Comment: What is it your doubting here, you didn't actually say, @AndreaNobili . In regard to your other questions:"OP" = "Original poster". `APPLY` allows for use of correlated sub queries in the `FROM`, In this case I use it in conjunction with the `VALUES` operator to apply expressions in the `FROM`; meaning I don't need to repeat them in the `SELECT`, `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` (although you can reference a column by it's alias in the `ORDER BY`).

Comment: You most often find `APPLY` used with functions, as you can't doing something like `FROM MyTable MT JOIN STRING_SPLIT(MT.MyColumn,',')`, as `MT.MyColumn` would not be known within the context of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping it in a try/catch block like this:

```
declare @vDate DATETIME
BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @vDate = CONVERT(datetime, '12/31/2010')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @vDate = null
END CATCH
SELECT @vDate
BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @vDate = CONVERT(datetime, 'eggs')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @vDate = null
END CATCH
SELECT @vDate
```